# update amcharts data in angular-amcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

I am using `amchart` to render a chart with JSON data which is an API response data,
and its working perfectly. Now I have to update the data on the basis of a selection dropdown which make a API call request to get the response JSON, which is also done now after getting the response data I don't know how to update the chart with the

```js
$scope.changeYearFunction = function(){
  console.log($scope.selectedYear);
  chartService.getDataByMonth($scope.selectedYear).then(function(response){
    $scope.monthdata = response.data;
 $scope.$apply();
  })
}
$scope.monthChart = function(year){
  chartService.getDataByMonth('2016').then(function(response){
    $scope.monthdata = response.data;
 $scope.finishloading = true;
 console.log($scope.monthdata);
 $scope.amChartOptions = {
  data : $scope.monthdata,
  type: "serial",
  theme: "light",
  marginRight: 80, 
  balloon: {
    cornerRadius: 6,
    horizontalPadding: 15,
    verticalPadding: 10
  },
  chartScrollbar: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  valueAxes: [{
    gridAlpha: 0.5,
    gridColor: '#dddddd',
  }],
  graphs: [{
    bullet: 'square',
    bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
    bulletBorderThickness: 1,
    fillAlphas: 0.5,
    //fillColorsField: 'lineColor',
    legendValueText: '[[value]]',
    //lineColorField: 'lineColor',
    title: 'power',
    valueField: 'power'
  }],
  chartCursor: {
    //categoryBalloonDateFormat: 'MMM',
     cursorAlpha: 0,
     fullWidth: true
  },
    //dataDateFormat: "MM",
    categoryField: "month",
  export: {
    enabled: true
  }      
   }
   })
 }();
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading"><span>Monthly Consumption</span>
 <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-change="changeYearFunction()">
  <option ng-repeat="x in year" value={{x}}>{{x}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div style="height: 450px; width: 100%;">
  <am-chart ng-if="finishloading" id="myAreaChart" options="amChartOptions"></am-chart>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset amchart with `ng-if` that already exist in your template. After data loaded you just `$scope.amChartOptions.data = $scope.monthdata`.

```
$scope.amChartOptions = {
                data : [],
                type: "serial",
                theme: "light",
                marginRight: 80,

                balloon: {
                    cornerRadius: 6,
                    horizontalPadding: 15,
                    verticalPadding: 10
                  },
                  chartScrollbar: {
                        enabled: true,
                    },
                valueAxes: [
                    {

                      gridAlpha: 0.5,
                      gridColor: '#dddddd',
                    }
                  ],
                graphs: [
                    {
                      bullet: 'square',
                      bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
                      bulletBorderThickness: 1,
                      fillAlphas: 0.5,
                      //fillColorsField: 'lineColor',
                      legendValueText: '[[value]]',
                      //lineColorField: 'lineColor',
                      title: 'power',
                      valueField: 'power'
                    }
                  ],

                  chartCursor: {
                      //categoryBalloonDateFormat: 'MMM',
                      cursorAlpha: 0,
                      fullWidth: true
                    },
                //dataDateFormat: "MM",
                categoryField: "month",

                export: {
                    enabled: true
                };

$scope.changeYearFunction = function(){

       $scope.finishloading = false;
       console.log($scope.selectedYear);
       chartService.getDataByMonth($scope.selectedYear).then(function(response){

           $scope.monthdata = response.data;
           $scope.finishloading = true;

           $scope.amChartOptions.data = $scope.monthdata;

           $scope.$apply();

       })
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: Yes, you need to have default amchart config. I updated my answer

Comment: Sorry for late reply, But Thank You for this fix, It works, But there is a one problem that when I load the page there is no data and then when I select the year then only the chart shows the data...

Comment: Ok, I fixed that Thank You